# How to configure Redis Cluster in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, cache, redis

I have installed and configured Redis Cache with Magento-2 and it's working fine.
For that, I added the config data in app/etc/env.php file.
Now I am trying to configure Redis Cluster with Magento-2 and checking how do the configuration.

Can anyone please help me how to configure Redis Cluster with Magento-2.

Comment: if you figure it out can you reply it here for others?